# LSTM RNN error when running it on Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, lstm, tensorflow2.0

I am on a Mac 2020 with an M1 chip so I installed TensorFlow via a Conda environment. This is TensorFlow 2.4, however when I try to run code that I had initially on another local machine, I had run into a NotImplementedError. To also note I am also on Python3.8
[image: RNN Error]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for anyone looking at this question but it's been resolved, the error was due to incompatibility between TensorFlow 2.4 and NumPy 1.20, downgrading NumPy to 1.19.5 fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your numpy version 1.20., try to install numpy version of 1.19.5 by using the command conda install numpy==1.19.5 and then excute this.